# how would it feel if I put paper clips in a U.S. outlet?

Tags: outlet

One paper clip for the left opening and one paper clip for the right opening of one single U.S. outlet. The paper clip on the left in my left hand and the paper clip on the right in my right hand.

Comment: Vote to close this totally off topic question.

Comment: I hope you're not considering this on purpose!  If so, *PLEASE* see a counselor first!

Comment: How would you feel if you smacked yourself in the face with a hammer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is North America with 120 Vac 60 Hz at your outlet, Somewhere between very unhappy and dead.  Depends on how moist your skin is where you are gripping the paper clips.

The issue here is that the current path crosses your chest and thus includes your heart within the current path.  There are detailed explanations on the web, but the human heart is very sensitive to 60 Hz current.  If there is enough external current reaching the heart, it can go into a condition called fibrillation.  The heart ceases beating normally and your blood circulation stops.

Unless emergency medical help gets to you quickly, you die.

Comment: How does how I grip the paper clips or where I grip the paper clips matter?

Comment: if you held both paper clips in the same hand, (like a paper clip between two pairs of fingers) the way the electricity travels through your body is very different to if there is one in each hand. In each hand, the current loop travels past/through your heart, basically killing you. If you had both clips in one hand, the electricity would flow through your hand/fingers, and probably explode/severely burn them.

Answer (score 2):

Contacting the AC hot wire and ground or neutral can result in a severe (possibly fatal) electric shock - **DO NOT TRY THIS AT HOME (or anywhere else, for that matter!)**